# Many LNK2019 errors when compiling OpenCL file

Tags: c++, opencl

I've been trying to use `OpenCL` in a `C++` file. When I try to compile it, it gives a lot of **LNK2019** errors, such as :

> unresolved external symbol _clGetPlatformIDs@12 referenced in function
>   "public: static int __cdecl cl::Platform::get(class std::vector > *)"
>   (?get@Platform@cl@@SAHPAV?$vector@VPlatform@cl@@V?$allocator@VPlatform@cl@@@std@@@std@@@Z)

The `Platform` class is defined in `cl.hpp`, and it uses `clGetPlatformIds`, defined in `cl.h` but not implemented. I think that is the problem. How can I make the code work ? (I have 24 unresolved external symbols)

Comment: "Unresolved external symbol" means it can't find that symbol; have you got the right project settings to link to the external library? Also, would be helpful to know what compiler/toolchain you're using so we can advise you better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LNK2019` is a Microsoft Visual Studio error. Add line `#pragma comment(lib, "OpenCL.lib")` to your source. You also should specify path to the library file in the project options: `Project/ Properties/ Configuration Properties / VC++ Directories / Library Directories`

Comment: Thank you, I did not add the pragma line, and the library file was only in the Linker options.

Comment: For me the library path was C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.5\lib\x64

Comment: This answer turned out to be insufficient in my case.  I was also trying to link with OpenCL.lib, and I couldn't get the right symbols out of it.  The root of the problem turned out to be that I was building for an x86 target whereas the .lib file had been built for an x64 target, or something like that.  I went into my Linker/Librarian options for each project involved, and also into the Configuration Manager, and in those two places I changed every relevant option from x86 to x64, or from Win32 to x64.  This removed the linker errors.